# Lazy loading not working for POCO classes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Please help me, I am new to EF.Lazy loading for POCO objects doesn't seem to be working.

- My POCO classes are in a sepearte assembly, other than the one one for Data access(i.e  DAL)
- The Data Acess layer simply wraps the calls made to the EF's object context. Please see the code below

  ```
  public FilterMaster GetFilter(long ID)
  {
      FilterMaster entity = new FilterMaster();
      try
      {
          using (var context = new RadarEntities())
          {                
              //context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
              //context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
              entity = context.FilterMasters.SingleOrDefault(filter => filter.ID == ID);
              //context.FilterMasters.Include(
              context.LoadProperty(entity, "SQLQuery");                   

          }
      }
  ```

  - When DAL call is completed, the ObjectContext is lost, and when I tried to fetch the related child objects of the Root POCO class, I get null.
  - I've tried explicitly enabling ProxyCreation, EnabledLazyLoading, checked the proxy clases generated are not sealed and all the related properties are marked virtual (as suggested on some other links).
    -As the lazy load was not working, I thought of eagerly loading all the related POCO objects, so tried invoking LoadProperty method, which works.

Q1: Am I Imissing something the lazy loading isn't working?

Q2: If I want to expelictly load all the related child objects the will have to call the LoadProperty method for all properties or there is any simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are disposing your `ObjectContext`.  This is what is preventing you from using LazyLoading.  If you need LazyLoading, the class containing `GetFilter` should create an `ObjectContext` when it is created, implement `IDisposable`, and dispose of the `ObjectContext` when it is disposed.

Comment: But then the purpose of POCO will be defeated as gthen woould become persistence aware. Right now only DAL API have refernce to ObjectContext.

Comment: @BrikeshKumar: But your upper layers have a reference to the DAL API class (or perhaps only an interface). You just need to hold the `ObjectContext` as a private member in that class and don't create and dispose it in every single method. The upper layers still don't see anything about the context. If you can't do this for whatever reason you have a lazy-loading-unfriendly architecture and can't really use lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks Slauma!!I am trying that. I took the Object context class out of the DAL project and am injecting it's instance in the DAL class constructor...Current running into issue of the context class not able  to find the metadata..

Comment: @BrikeshKumar Great.  Please don't forget to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1: Am I Imissing something the lazy loading isn't working?

It's working but there is no magic involved - underneath a proxy is created for you which will try to retrieve the property value from the database for you on the first access.

For EF the database connection is represented by the context, which you currently dispose automatically at the end of your using block. Without database connection EF cannot lazily retrieve the properties and hence lazy loading won't work.

You will have to keep the context alive until you have accessed all the properties you need to access for lazy loading, or alternatively eagerly load those properties.

> Q2: If I want to explicitly load all the related child objects the
>   will have to call the LoadProperty method for all properties or there
>   is any simpler way?

Yes, you can specify an `Include()` query to eagerly retrieve properties, in your case that would be:

```
 entity = context.FilterMasters
                 .Include("SQLQuery")
                 .SingleOrDefault(filter => filter.ID == ID);
```

Comment: I think there is only the string version of `Include` because `context` is an `ObjectContext`.

Comment: thanks Slauma, I'm so used to the strongly typed version, will update

Comment: Yes I see only one version of the Include function that takes a string. Also If I do an eager load then I'll have write a line for each properties in the entire object graph.

Comment: BrokenGlass, Is there a way to eager load the entire object graph without specifying each dependent object in the Include function.